# A cloning question involving quantum entanglement

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement

Firstly, I am not exactly an expert at this, and I have only just found out about quantum entanglement.

So from what I know, quantum entanglement allows information from one atom to be "copied" to another.

Could it be possible, with some technology that allows us to instantly complete this process, to copy all the atoms that make up a human to another location and effectively clone them?

Comment: No need to use quantum entanglement for this. A classical cloner would do. https://xkcd.com/465/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no. Quantum entanglement does not allow cloning. The premise is wrong due to the [no cloning theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-cloning_theorem). An unknown quantum state cannot be copied exactly without destroying the original state. Entanglement has nothing to do with it.

So if by cloning we imagine, making two copies of an object up to the quantum atomic level, then the answer is that it is not possible.

Comment: Just to add to this correct answer: the concept underlying the original premise is called "quantum teleportation" (which is real).  An unknown quantum state can be teleported (cloned if you will) but not without destroying the original state.  Entanglement is used for such teleportation.

Comment: "Cloned if you will"? No!